# Prevent button on expansion header to trigger the panel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a delete button in the header section of my expansion panel.
Clicking on the delete button should not show/hide expands the panel, it is for dialogue. Instead, it also expands the panel. How do I prevent it from expanding the panel?

[image]

```
<v-expansion-panel-header>
  {{ vehicle.VIN }}

  <v-icon v-if="type == 'saved'" color="teal"> mdi-check </v-icon>
  <v-btn
    text
    class="flex-grow-0"
    v-if="type == 'saved'"
    color="red"
    @click="remove(index, type)"
  >
    DELETE
  </v-btn>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

Live Issue : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/gv1zech7/

Comment: Try `@click.prevent="remove(index, type)"`. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

Comment: It somehow still expand the panel with that `@click.prevent="remove(index, type)"` added to my delete btn.

Comment: Have you checked the z-index? Also, could you create a sandbox example? https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-montalcini-nx9siu?file=/src/main.js

Comment: I have not check z-index. I tried with span and even diable button. Anything in the headers seem to trigger panel expansion by default.

https://share.cleanshot.com/ORHvsL

Comment: @bassxzero Easily reproduce here : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/gv1zech7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `.stop` [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers):

```
  <v-btn
    text
    class="flex-grow-0"
    v-if="type == 'saved'"
    color="red"
    @click.stop="remove(index, type)"
  >
    DELETE
  </v-btn>
```